# iOS: using SVG (PocketSVG) for hundreds of image assets

Tags: ios, svg, uibezierpath, vector-graphics

One of our team member is urging to use SVGs using github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG, instead of regular assets @1x @2x @3x. We have over a hundred image sets.

I have 2 questions:

1) 100s of SVG data rendered using PocketSVG or even another library, is that gonna be a performance kill?

2) Using SVGs over regular assets, going to make any different visually, though our designer have these all images extracted properly using vectors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer for first Question :** Yes, Whenever trying to show an image on the screen, it will process your SVG file and create a new image assets. May be the library can cache the image to avoid second time processing.

**You no need to use PocketSVG if you have all SVG images on your Asset Catalog. Because Xcode Asset catalog itself able to handle the SVG images.**

Xcode will create @1x @2x @3x images from SVG file at the time of compilation.

**Answer for second Question :** SVG is a vector image. You can extract good quality image from svg. You will not get any different by using @1x @2x @3x images or SVG image.

The advantage of using SVG is no need to create one more asset @4x if Apple introduced another different screen resolution devices. Just recompile the code Xcode will create on behalf of you

***Refer the link*** : [How to use vector in Xcode](https://icons8.com/articles/how-to-use-vectors-in-xcode-7/)

Comment: in section `Answer for second Question`: We intending to use PocketSVG to create CG/UIPaths at runtime, not assets, are you sure in this case we will not get any improvement visually

Comment: If you have good quality images of 1x 2x 3x then you will get the same effect of PocketSVG too. Because It is based on iPhone screen resolution & your image resolution.